# Is this cryptic valid?

Tags: cryptic-clues

I came up with a cryptic clue that I'd like to use, but I'm not sure if it's valid.

> Less hair?—nonsense! (10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Less hair? —
>  balder dash
>  **balderdash**
>  nonsense
>
>  I solved the clue but I'm not sure if using the punctuation is valid.  The question mark is redundant. But if you create a puzzle, perhaps you can be creative with the rules too...